# How do you get a connection string from the appsettings.json in .netCore 1.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am following this post:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration

I am not seeing they are accessing the properties here. When I do something like this:

```
public MyRepository(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _connectionString = $"{configuration["MyConnectionString"]}";
}
```

All I get back are nulls or empty strings

appconfig.json

```
 "ConnectionString": {
    "MyConnectionString": "CorrectConnectionString"

}
```

If I inspect the configuration during runtime. I can see that the connectionstring is stored in it, I just can't figure out how to access it.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you registered the Configuration instance in your `ConfigureServices` method in Startup.cs ?
Like so: `services.AddSingleton(Configuration);` If you don't it cannot be used in DI, as you're attempting to use it now.

Comment: @ErikBožič Yes. I have all the information in the configuration object that I need. I just cant seem to find the proper way to get it out

Comment: Oh, well you should probably be accessing it like: `$"{configuration["ConnectionString:MyConnectionString"]}"`
In fact, I belive the default way is ConnectionString**s**. In which case you could use `configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")`

Comment: @ErikBožič if you put that as an answer then I will accept it. I am not sure why I was having such a hard time. In hindsight it was obvious.

Comment: sometimes it's the obvious little things you miss. Happens. I also didn't notice it when I first looked at the question.
Yes, will post in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `MyConnectionString` property is defined inside `ConnectionString` object you need to access it like:

```
public MyRepository(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _connectionString = $"{configuration["ConnectionString:MyConnectionString"]}";
}
```